# What compressor type does 2010 Lexus RX450h use

Tags: ac, lexus

I'm a student studying motive power program at a college. Our instructor gave us an assignment to find out the specific vehicle's compressor type and which component is used TXV (throttle expansion valve) or orifice tube. My vehicle is 2010 Lexus RX450h. I just find it too hard to find it on website so I wonder if someone could tell me and would give me the website address. I'll really appreciate it! Please help me. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The compressor is a scroll type driven by a variable speed 288 volt three phase motor. The speed is controlled by the A/C system controller that uses neural network logic to calculate the required refrigerant volume needed based on learned values of this vehicle in its usual climate and usage pattern.

As for the TVX vs Tube question. The system uses a newer style micropore orifice tube design that is built into the evaporator.

Comment: Thank you very much sir! But sir, would you tell me which website or manual book do you search to find these stuff?

Comment: In 30+ years in automotive diagnostics I have collected lots of sources.

Comment: @FredWilson You should write a book :)

Comment: @User11975 The source for this was from Toyotas info website. Not free and not easy to navigate.  @ HandyHowie No books yet, but I do teach seminars.

Comment: Again, nice detail and fact based.