# chevrolet, Impala 2012, 3.6 LS

Tags: chevrolet

I am a student, I need some information about Impala 2012. any one please help me. air condition compressor type, it's automatic or manual control ?

Comment: Somebody call @FredWilson.  He seems to know a lot [about compressors](http://mechanics.stackexchange.com/a/22554/12030).  This must be the semester for A/C in many courses...